# How to create dynamic map objects in a loop

Tags: java, mysql, dictionary, hashmap

```
//Mysql Query to get project

while(query.next())
{
    Map objname=new Hashmap();
    //Mysql query to get day and hours of respective project
    while(dayandhourquery.next())
    {
        objname.put(day,hour);
    }
}
```

I've a query to get project name,days and hours.and I want to put day and hours in Hashmap with respective project.
While doing this above code,I am getting the details with the last project.

Comment: I don't really understand what the actual problem is here, do you mind clarifying?

Comment: My first query gives me the project.With this project name I am fetching the day and hours. For each project I am adding day and hours in map. But right now with my logic I am getting the day and hours but only for last project name not for every project.

Comment: Hi @spydon is there any way to change MAP object dynamically...

Answer (score 1):

It happen because `Map` stores only values for unique keys.
I assume that for project days could be the same.
When you put `day` value you override old day-hour entry in map.
You need to consider changing key value in map or use one collection for each project.

Comment: Hi Areo can you please share me any example if you have ??

Comment: In your `while` loop you need to get project identifier. Based on it you need to add day-hour entry to correct collection.  First solution could be having `Map<String, List<DayTimeEntry>` where `key` is your project id and `DayTimeEntry` is a class that holds day and hour information.

Comment: For every project there is different day and hour information.We need day as key and hour as value for each project.Can you give with an example?